# 表示不正: ヘルプ「Markdown または HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定する方法は?」の「画像」の説明

Tags: バグ, 完了

ヘルプ「Markdown または HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定する方法は?」の「画像」の説明に不正な表示がある。具体的には以下（Markdownの部分）。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

英語版だと以下のように正しく表示されている。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 関連: http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/233/%e8%8b%b1%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%8c%e6%ae%8b%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b-%e3%83%98%e3%83%ab%e3%83%97-markdown-%e3%81%be%e3%81%9f%e3%81%af-html-%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e7%94%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e6%8a%95%e7%a8%bf%e3%82%92%e6%9b%b8%e5%bc%8f%e8%a8%ad%e5%ae%9a%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95%e3%81%af-%e3%81%ae-%e7%94%bb%e5%83%8f-%e3%81%ae%e8%aa%ac%e6%98%8e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

本件、修正されている事を[ヘルプページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)で確認しました（以下）。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]